# Merge single cells in LyX table without ERT

Tags: tables, lyx

Basically, I want to merge single cells in a LyX table without using ERT (hopefully) to get something similar to:

[image: Table example]

To clarify, cells of Headline 1 and 2 are merged vertically and Headline 3 horizontally.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer myself.

In Windows, select cells in question > Right click > "More..." > "Multicolumn" or "Multirow".

Comment: There's also the Table toolbar that should pop up at the bottom when you're inside a table. One of the buttons is for making the selection into a multicell.

Answer (score 1):

Lyx 2.3: Select cells -> `Right click` -> `Columns/Rows` (at the bottom) -> `Multicolumn`/`Multirow`.